# postgreSQL to select value of yesterday, month average

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table:

```
create table UV(
f_date int,
uv bigint
)
```

data:

```
f_date   |   uv 
---------+-------
20150103 | 620964 
20150104 | 595367
```

So how to generate such a table using sql:

```
f_date   |   uv_today | uv_yesterday |  uv_month_avg
---------+------------+--------------+--------------
20150103 | 620964     |(uv of 20150102)| average uv from 20141204 to 20150103
20150104 | 595367     |  620964        |
```

Comment: Slightly less than absolutely minimal sample data is useful, though this sure is better than nothing.

Comment: Why are you using a bigint for date? You should store your dates in a  `date` column.

Comment: I'll try to fix my schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Do *not* store dates as integers! Use `date` if you want a date! Especially do not store date as integers with place-value used to signify year, month and day. Seriously. You need to fix this schema before you proceed with actually using it. Either store epoch values as julian dates, or use the native data types `date`, `timestamp` and `interval` for proper date/time work.

The first part is a trivial application of a window function; just `lag(uv, 1) OVER (ORDER BY f_date)`.

The second is a bit trickier, but it's not too bad once you fix your schema. You can use `avg(uv) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', f_date))`, assuming you want a calendar month. If you want a 30-day interval, that's a different matter.

So something like:

```
create table UV(
f_date date,
uv bigint
);

insert into UV (f_date, uv)
VALUES ('20150103', '620964'),
       ('20150104', '595367');

SELECT
  f_date,
  uv,
  lag(uv, 1) OVER (ORDER BY f_date),
  avg(uv) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', f_date))
FROM UV;
```

as shown: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c953f/1

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with sub-selects in the the select list:

```
select f_date,
       uv as uv_today,
       (select uv from uv as u2
        where u2.f_date = uv.f_fdate - 1) as uv_yesterday,
       (select avg(uv) from uv as u2
        where u2.f_date between uv.f_fdate - 30 and uv.f_fdate) as uv_month_avg
from uv
```

Note that I didn't care to calculate minus 1 month correctly, since I don't know how that is done in postgresql, just took - 30 days instead.

Comment: `- interval '1' month`

Comment: @CraigRinger, even when the date is stored as int?

Comment: I only noticed that after making that comment. In that case the correct thing to do is *not store the date as int, because that's horrible*. Or cast it or whatever.